# Online browsing is unavailable in visual studio

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on visual studio 2013 Ultimate, and in New project Wizard I search for a new templates under Online title but have this message : 
**Online browsing is unavailable. Please ensure you have a network connection to the internet**.
I don't think that the problem is related to my network. If any one could help me.

Comment: This is a not a programming question. This is a technical support issue for a particular product.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS or restarting your computer?